# how to add custom label in address book below first name and last name in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

how to add custom label in address book below first name and last name in ios[image]

Comment: you mean in the contacts app?

Comment: You cant access address book directly. You need to access the contents of address book and display them as you want.

Comment: Please give the comments according to the below deleted answer?

Comment: @ user3182143 : what do you mean? How we can see deleted answer? @vikas: bhagyalaxmi solution is right. also please explain what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
    -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        UILabel *lbl;


        if (cell == nil) 
{
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        }


       UILabel * lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,200 ,40 )];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
      return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to add text to Apple's Contacts App, you cannot. You can add contacts to the data their app accesses, but you cannot change Apple's UI.

If you want to roll your own contacts app similar to Apple's, use a UITableView and with the UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle.